# Classical hourglass time measurement exercise with linear equation systems.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, discrete-mathematics, puzzle, least-squares

I sometimes visit Puzzling StackExchange, and this time I found [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/54195/measure-22-minutes-with-7-and-13-minute-hourglasses). Which I found particuarly interesting, because I suspect that maybe it can be solved with linear equation systems.

To formulate the question:

---

Assume we have a set of hourglasses $\mathcal H = \{h_1,h_2,\cdots,h_n\}$ running for $\{m_1,m_2,\cdots,m_n\}$ minutes.

How can we arrange their flipping to measure $N$ minutes?

Comment: This is possible for any $N$ only if the running times are coprime natural numbers.